# Do surjective morphism exists between the Riemann surfaces $\Bbb P^1$ and $\Bbb C$ ? Can they be extended to a morphism $\Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb P^1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

How can I prove the existence or not of a surjective morphisms of Riemann surfaces $\Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb C$ ? and $\Bbb C \to \Bbb  P^1$? In case that it exists, how can I prove if there's any that can be extended to a morphism $\Bbb P^1\to \Bbb P^1$? $\Bbb P^1$ is the complex projective space.  Morphism here means a holomorphic maps between Riemann surfaces

It should be enough to find and example to prove the existance but I can't come up with any.

Comment: $\mathbb P^1$ is?

Comment: What do you think and what did you try to solve this? (By the way, you should explain what do you mean by a "morphism", given your tags, this probably means a holomorphic map.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the complex projective space

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes holomoprhic maps between Rieman surfaces. The thing is that I find it difficult to deal with projective spaces, so I can't come up with examples

Comment: One direction is easy: $\mathbb{P}^1$ is compact, so there are no surjective maps from it onto $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Think about some rational functions. "Most" will yield surjective maps $\mathbb C\to \mathbb P^1=\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: @BenSteffan How can I check that?. By Absurd, if there were a surjective map , then holomorphicity implies continuity and then the image which is the complex plane woud have to be compact , but that is not true. Is this correct?

Comment: @MoisheKohan So I don't have to worry about singularities because they are map to infinitiy? For instance $f(z)=(z-2)/(z-1)$ maps to $\Bbb P^1$? I thought that would not work because singularities are not supposed to be in the the domain, so in my example the domain of f is is $\Bbb C\setminus \{1\}$ and not $\Bbb C$. So at this point only polynomials work in order to have $\Bbb C$ as domain ? Secondly how do I get the homogeneos coordinates that characterize the projective space?

Comment: It sounds as if there are questions underlying this one, such as "What is the relationship between holomorphic and meromorphic functions and holomorphic maps to the projective line?", without whose answers an answer to this one will be difficult to understand.

Comment: No, linear-fractional transformations will not work. A pole at $p$ for a meromorphic function $f: U\to \mathbb C$ means that you can extend $f$ holomorphically  to $p$ and obtain a map $U\cup \{p\}\to \mathbb P^1$. At this point, you lack enough of understanding of complex analysis and my suggestion is to think of $\mathbb P^1$ as the Riemann sphere. Identifying with $\mathbb P^1$ is a separate matter which was discussed many times on mathstackexchange.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Why won't my example work if I do what you described?. $\Bbb C\setminus \{1\}$ was the original domain and now extending by $\{1\}$
 would yield $\Bbb C$  and then map to $\Bbb P^1$ holomorphically via my function (which is meromorphic)

Comment: It is a good algebra exercise to work out why linear-fractional transformations are 1-1 and, hence, can never map $\mathbb C$ onto $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: When you asked and received an answer to a [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883920/do-surjective-morphisms-bbb-c-times-to-bbb-c-and-viceversa-between-riemann), did that answer not provide ideas that help here?